# Issues with Next.js 13 Dynamic Routes Generating .txt Instead of .html for New Products

Tags: next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing, dynamic-routing

I'm facing an issue with my Next.js 13 application's router involving dynamic routes and the generation of static pages. I've successfully implemented a dynamic route to fetch a single item using its product ID, utilizing generateStaticPaths. However, I've encountered an unexpected behavior after deploying my project. New product pages are being created with a .txt extension instead of the expected .html extension.

Here's a snippet of the relevant code from my project:

```
async function getProduct(id) {
    const product = await fetch(
        `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}/v1/store/${id}`
    ).then((res) => res.json());
    return product;
}
export async function generateStaticParams() {
    const products = await fetch(
        `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}/v1/store/`
    ).then((res) => res.json());

    return products.map((product) => ({
        id: product._id,
    }));
}

const SingleStore = async ({ params: { id } }) => {
        const product = await getProduct(id);
    const removePTags = (text) => {
        const regex = /<p[^>]*>(.*?)<\/p>/g;
        return text?.replace(regex, '$1');
    };
    return ( <h1>My product Implementation </h1> )
}
```

I expect that when new products are added to the product list after the project has been built and deployed, the new product pages should be created with a .html extension, just like the existing product pages.

However, after deploying the project, new product pages are being generated with a .txt extension, which is causing unexpected behavior and broken links.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.